Closed sets and limit points
I am trying to prove the following result concerning a closed set and a limit point of a set in a metric space $X$.
Let $X$ be a metric space, and let $C$ be a subset of $X$. The following are equivalent.

$C$ is closed.
If $(a_n)$ is a sequence in $C$ converging to $x \in X$, then $x \in C$.

I am using the definition: A set $C$ is closed if it contains all its limit points.
For the Theorem above, $(2) \implies (1)$ is easy. I need you to check if you agree with my $(1) \implies (2)$ proof.
Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence in $C$ converging to $x\in X$. By definition of convergence for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n > N$, $d(a_n,x) < \epsilon$. That implies $\forall \epsilon>0$, the ball $B_{\epsilon}(x)\setminus\{x\}$ contains infinitely many elements of $C$, which means $x$ is a limit point of $C$. Now since $C$ is closed, then $x \in C$ and hence $(2)$ is proved.
Is there any problem with the proof?

Minor correction: in "contains infinitely many elements of $C$ for all $n > N$", the "for all $n > N$" can be removed.
Beyond this, it looks fine, but I think you can simplify it a little because you only need to show, for any $\epsilon > 0$, that $B_\epsilon(x) \setminus {x}$ has one point of $C$. (It is true that for any $\epsilon$ it contains infinitely many points of $C$, but you don't need that to show that $x$ is a limit point.)

That is true. We don't need infinitely many. But I was hoping if the proof was right.

There may be points of $C$ which need not be limit points (i.e. the set $C$ may be closed but not perfect) -- in which case, if you consider the constant sequence ${x}$, for $x \in C$, and $x$ is an isolated point, there may exist a neighborhood of $x$ which does not contain any point of $C$ other than $x$ -- so the statement in the proof should be revised to "every open ball $B_\epsilon(x)$ contains infinitely many points of the "sequence" (rather than of $C$).

It should not be $B_{\epsilon}(x) \backslash {x}$ in the proof.
